# Counter-intuitive weight in logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression

I have a question about logistic regression.

One of the features I built is a binary feature which produces either 0 or 1. The number of the positive instances with the feature activated is ~110K while the number of the negative instances is only 57. So, I expected a high positive weight for the feature. However, the learned weight is a high negative.

One possible reason could be a high learning-rate which prevented hitting the global minima. Other than that, could there be any other reason?

I'm using sklearn. The total # of training instances is 1.3M.

Comment: How many features total do you have?  It will be hard to answer without more information, but it's probably worth checking if this feature is correlated with any other features in your regression.  See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74138/correlated-features-produce-strange-weights-in-logistic-regression

Comment: @bogovicj Thanks. That was exactly the reason. When I removed another feature which looked like being correlated, the weight looks fine.